# Best practice to alter the attributes variable in a Drupal 8 Twig template

Tags: theming, 8

I'm creating a custom Drupal 8 theme based on [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). (NOTE. I'm aware of https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap, I just want some practice.)

More often than not, I find myself adding Bootstrap classes to the existing Drupal classes via the `Attribute` object already available in the template.

For instance, in Bootstrap, the main navigation menu looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">...</ul>
```

What is the best practice is to add the `nav navbar-nav` classes to Drupal's `menu.html.twig` template? This template already contains the following line:

```
<ul{{ attributes}}>
```

**1) Add the classes with a preprocess function?**

I could add the following function to my `MYTHEME.theme` file to alter the `attributes` variable before it's passed to the template:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['menu_name'] == 'main') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'nav';
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'navbar-nav';
  }
}
```

**2) Add the classes directly inside the Twig template?**

First, I'd create a template named `menu--main.html.twig` to override only Drupal's main menu.

Then, I'd alter the line with the `<ul>` to:

```
<ul{{ attributes.addClass(['nav', 'navbar-nav']) }}>
```

I find #2 a little less clean but it keeps all the markup in the same place.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

If it is your theme then I would do it in a template. Drupal Core converted a lot of preprocess/template to work like that, e.g. the node template.

The advantage is that everything is together as you said and it's a lot easier change it later.

Also if you're a module that defines a template, then someone can just copy that, adjust it and have full control over the classes.

Comment: I am indeed creating a theme. I tend to agree with you, but even if I put my code in the `THEME.theme` file  (in a preprocess function), it would still be packaged with the theme, not in a module.

Comment: I agree with Berdir. A good example is the classy theme in core, which brings back some of the drupal 7 divs and classes. This theme only uses twig templates, no php: `/core/themes/classy`